# How to replace storing a variable with a built in?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am building a nth root calculator (without importing `math`) using Newton’s method and also aims to round to the user liking to minimize computation time.

However I have to store a variable to compare a previous value with current value, and am not sure if the code will always produce the correct answer (ignore even roots of negative value for now).

Is there anyway to not use a stored variable and further increase speed of my computation? Here is the code:

```
x,n,acc=[float(i) for i in input().split()]

def newton_nthroot(x,n,acc):
    value=1
    while True:
        store=value
        value += (x-(value**n))/(n*(value**(n-1)))
        if round(value,acc) == round(store,acc):
            break
    print(round(value,acc))

newton_nthroot(x,n,int(acc))
```

Comment: You mentioned not being sure that your code will always produce the correct answer - but notice that your question is not related to it, only to computation speed...

Comment: This is my second smaller question, so do I need to create another post for this?

Comment: I'm not sure that you have to, but do edit your question so that the difference is clear...

Comment: The fact that the values of the successive iterations are close to each other doesn't mean that they are close to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that losing `store` will actually increase speed, but I've noticed that you are calculating `value` by adding `(((x-(value**n)))/(n*(value**(n-1)))` (let's call this expression `z`), and then comparing `value` to `store`. 
 You can, if you want, just calculate `z` and compare it to 0:

```
def newton_nthroot(x,n,acc):
    value=1
    while True:
        z = (x-(value**n))/(n*(value**(n-1)))           
        if round(z,acc) == 0:
            break
        else:
            value +=z
    print(round(value,acc))
```